# Passing a web page string into AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to pass the string of entire web pages into an AWS lambda function to perform some scraping.

To do this I am using AWS API Gateway. Is there a maximum size my POST method can be in AWS API Gateway as some of these web pages will be rather large?

Comment: You can upload the content to S3 and pass the URL to Lambda to download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum payload in API Gateway is currently 10MB and this cannot be changed (see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_apigateway)) although the limit may be raised at some point in time in the future.